# is there a theory consider on infinitely many recursion?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, recursion

of course there is a theory that how many recursive calling the same system to solve problems, this theory is "recursion theory", If i know correctly.

and recursion theory is computability theory.

but where is the theory that deals with infinitely many calling or endless self-reference, so that one can identify such blackbox systems from finite or whitebox systems.

my question is not, "is there a theory that deals with the conversion of infinite recursive system to finite recursive system" or "is there the methodology to control the blackbox systems".

I just have mean, "is there a theory deals with the property and structure of infinitely recursive systems as itself (with constructive or formal view?)"

thanks!

Comment: Mathematical fractals is the closest thing to "infinite recursion" I could think about

Comment: You might be interested in the terms "hypertask" and "hypercomputation," which lie in the subject of ***generalized*** (or ***higher***) **computability/recursion theory**.